# Flyway repeatable migration for a view can't be dropped

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway, create-view

We have a bunch of views in postgres that are created as repeatable migrations by Flyway.

The error that we have encountered is that if we want to rename a column by using `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`, postgres throws an error and cannot do so.

One option is to drop the view first. But this causes a problem if something else depends on the view, which will also throw an error.

Is there any way of dealing with this without having to write complicated scripts to drop any tables/views that depend on this view as that will also require recreating the other views. This process can get very messy and wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `CREATE OR REPLACE` for it because it was designed to extend column list:

> [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createview.html)
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW is similar, but if a view of the same name already exists, it is replaced. **The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the same column names in the same order and with the same data types)**, but it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

Options:

- make changes that are backward compatible i.e. only adding new columns
- drop and recreate view(you need to handle the object dependencies)

---

Flyway is migration-based tool, you could search for "state-based" migration tool  for PostgreSQL(SQL Server has SSDT). Related [State- or migrations-based database development](http://assets.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/state-or-migrations-based-database-development.pdf)

[6 Version Control tools for PostgreSQL](https://dbmstools.com/version-control-tools/postgresql)

> **State-based tools - generate the scripts for database upgrade by comparing database structure to the model (etalon).**
>
> Migration-based tools - help/assist creation of migration scripts for moving database from one version to next.